# ultrafast catch diode for relay

Tags: switching, inductive

Is there any reason to not use a UF2008 as catch diode on a DC relay, solenoid, or electromagnet?  IN4001 costs $0.07 and UF2008 costs $0.03 and seems to be better suited in all ways

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm59pB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Old parts tend to persist due to people using them by habit, or because they read old books and those use old parts. See the number of newbie questions involving a new circuit and a 741 op amp - OTOH, sometimes the older part is both cheaper and adequate, so it's good enough. In this case, you seem to have value engineered to a "better" part, which happens when better parts get cheaper due to volume, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either diode is fine in this application as long as the relay coil current is less than 2 amps.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing small quantity or are flexible you may be fine with them, but keep in mind that the real manufacturer is apparently not known and it may be a surplus lot that will be unavailable the next time you go to buy, according to [this](http://www.beesnotincluded.com/2012/06/who-are-multicomp.html) source.

1N400x (and the SMT equivalents) are very cheap in quantity and can be found in all kinds of consumer goods, now and in the future.

Comment: Yeah, Multicomp is Farnell Group's house brand.  I hadn't noticed that was the brand on these diodes.  I've ordered probably enough for several years when I run out I'll probably get *soup du jour* again.

Comment: @Jasen - You might want to qualify the diode forward recovery time in either case (1N4007 or UF2008), this [Linear Tech app note AN122](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an122f.pdf) describes the potential problem. I encountered it just yesterday as it happens, and resolved it indirectly through a post by Spehro, hence why I comment on this reply. In my case, the voltage spike at the transistor (drain in my case) went into avalanche territory as the inductor was "waiting" for the diode to turn on. Unfortunately \$T_{FR}\$ is not usually specified, so I imagine requires testing.

Answer (score 1):

Do we really need nanoseconds diodes for this application? Transistors switching the relay solenoids not always driven in such a way where it turn on or off in nanoseconds, as such, the di/dt in the coil could be slow enough for low speed diodes.

Cheap high performance components might not be always available. Don't count on them unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

The title of the question is "ultrafast..."; the release speed of the circuit you show has virtually nothing to do the the speed of the diode. When the transistor turns off, the current continues to flow in the coil, and the relay continues to hold in the ON position until that energy is dissipated.  It takes a long time because the effective diode resistance is quite low, so the L/R time constant is very long.  Solution is to insert a resistor in SERIES with the diode, start with a resistance about the same as the relay coil DC resistance.  This will allow the collector voltage to fly up to about double the supply voltage (as opposed to supply voltage plus a diode drop), but will allow MUCH faster operation.

Comment: To clarify: the OP is asking about turn-on speed of the diode (to minimise inductive kick on the transistor. This answer is about minimising relay drop time.

Comment: Agreed, but note that the inductive kick comes when the transistor turns off.  And the turn OFF time will dominate how fast the relay can switch.  The "Magic" resistor is a fix I have used many times in years past, it makes a big difference.

Comment: so long as the magic smoke, and the EMI stays inside I'm happy.  UF2008 has a higher Vf but 1N4001 is fast enough. I know fast diodes may require snubbers when used in rectifier bridges.