# Power two connected circuits with one battery

Tags: microcontroller, motor, relay

I want to use a 9v 1200mAh battery to simultaneously provide current to a 9-12v motor and microcontroller. The microcontroller would ideally switch the motor circuit, which would derive power from the battery. The reason I want to do this rather than use two separate power sources or power the motor through the microcontroller is that the microcontroller only has an output of 6v, making the motor either useless or underpowered. The constraints do not allow for multiple power sources.

Is there a way to feasibly do what I'm hoping? I don't have much of a background in electronics or EE, not entirely sure where to begin with this.

Comment: You don't have to use separate power sources as long as the battery can supply a sufficient amount of current. And can't you use a transistor to switch different voltages?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this a duplicate of one of the other "power two things of one battery" questions

Comment: If the battery is a PP3 and the motor isn't absolutely tiny, the answer is simple : don't...

Answer (score 1):

It's normally done like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8SZjJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The diode D1 is probably not needed, most motors behave more like capacitors than inductors

Comment: Best to still keep the fly back diode tho.

Comment: Better still to use a decent fast diode rather than a 4001.

Comment: that transistor is going to be fairly slow turning off, IN4001 is plenty fast enough,  but hey if a UF2008 is cheaper there no reason not to. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/242197/ultrafast-catch-diode-for-relay